# recommendations for test data set(s) known to have well separated clusters

Tags: clustering, data-visualization

I am working on visualizing clusters in high dimensional space. I have had good luck with "real" data sets contributed to the UCI Machine Learning repository. Unfortunately, none of these data sets have really well separated clusters. I've used "artificial", machine generated, data sets which have well separated clusters, as constructed, but I am looking for a data set that is freely available and is known to well separated clusters.

By well separated clusters I am thinking of ones which would lend themselves to a high Dunn Index.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You might (also) try asking on [Open Data SE](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions seeking datasets are off-topic for CV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some old data sets at http://ggobi.org/book/. Look at the flea, olive and crabs data. There is a pdf file with descriptions of all of the data sets on that page too. Each of these three data sets has well separated clusters, some matching the class variable(s) provided, but you can ignore the class variable to do cluster analysis. There are nuisance variables in each of the data sets, which may interfere with the clustering. Here are some pictures of 2D projections of the different data sets that show some clusters:

flea

[image]

olive

[image]

crabs

[image]